# Number of busy connections used in pool

Tags: node.js, postgresql, connection-pooling

I am using connection pool in **pg** node js module.

As I understand when you are using connection pool, your connections created for you, and stored, when you need it, some method evoked, and you get already instantiated connection.

**Now about pg:**

Simple code

```
pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      client.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, result) {
        done();
        if (err) callback(err);
        callback(null, result.rows);
      });
    }
  });
```

When I call `pg.connect` method, I assume that, I get already instantiated connection from pool, when I call `done` I return my connection to the pool.

Now I want to debug my application, I can forgot to call `done` or do it not efficient way.

**How can I print number of busy connections? Or another way to debug approach. Thank you in advance.**

I had some problem, when request to my route hanging for 30 seconds, I suppose that it is, because I didn't return my connection to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

From pg module [documentation pages](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/pools)

```
var pg = require('pg');

pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  var pool = pg.pools.getOrCreate();
  console.log(pool.getPoolSize()); //1
  console.log(pool.availableObjectsCount()); //0
  done();
  console.log(pool.getPoolSize()); //1
  console.log(pool.availableObjectsCount()); //1
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it prints 0, 0 ,0, 0 . What does it mean?

Comment: it is the output of the getPoolSize and availableObjectsCount functions, I advise you study the documentation for the 'pg' module to learn what it means, the link is in my answer

Comment: I think what @SlowHarry meant is that it always seems to return 0 for `getPoolSize` and `availableObjectsCount`. I came here for that reason, having already read the documentation. Even when testing under load with Apache Bench I never see anything other than 0 for these calls.